# Add constant value to numeric XML attribute

Tags: vim, editing, regex, find-and-replace

### Background

Add a constant value to numbers matched with a regular expression, using vim (gvim).

### Problem

The following regular expression will match `width="32"`:

```
/width="\([0-9]\{2\}\)"
```

### Question

How do you replace the numeric value of the `width` attribute with the results from a mathematical expression that uses the attribute's value? For example, I would like to perform the following global replacement:

```
:%s/width="\([0-9]\{2\}\)"/width="\1+10"/g
```

That would produce `width="42"` for `width="32"` and `width="105"` for `width="95"`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do expression evaluation in the substitution, see:

```
:help :s\=
:help submatch()
```

For example:

```
:%s/width="\([0-9]\{2\}\)"/\='width="'.(submatch(1)+10).'"'/g
```

When you do expression substitution the entire substitution must be an expression, so you have to concatenate (see `:help expr-.`) the three elements of the expression. Broken down:

- `\=`

Indicate the replacement pattern is an expression.

- `'width="'`

The first string.

- `(submatch(1) + 10)`

Add ten to the first sub-pattern-match—enclosed in parenthesis so Vim doesn't try to include the preceding string in the addition operation.

- `'"'`

The closing quote as a string.

(Note that I did not include the concatenation operators in the breakdown.)